# Set a timer between two button clicks

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an Excel file with an Userform to control how long it takes for some people to complete a set of tasks.

I have an Userform that opens on start up and as soon as you click the button on it, the time starts counting. However, I don't really understand how I can do that.

I need the timer to run until the task is complete and the user clicks "Exit" or "Complete" and then save the time to my spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you know how to program in VBA?

Comment: Do you want the time to display on the screen as it counts up or just to record the time between the two events?

Comment: @peakpeak I used to. But the lat time I did was in High School. 10 years ago.

Comment: @RobAnthony I want the time to display on the screen as it counts and when the form is closed, I need to record that time on a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Barbaaz To record the time at the start and end of the calculation you can use `Now`. See my answer below. The difference between is the elapsed time.

Comment: @Petrichor I am using a label to show the timer on the screen as it counts and I want to record the caption when I finish the task.

Comment: Do you mean "control how long", or "measure how long"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose slightly different approach. In the userform, declare variables:

```
Private startTime As Double
Private endTime As Double
Private blTime As Boolean
```

blTime is double that tells the application that the clock goes on. Then set value for startTime when userform is launched:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    startime = Time
    blTime = True
End Sub
```

I have assumed thet your button complete control is named cbComplete. Change to your button's real name

```
Private Sub cbComplete_Click()
    If blTime Then endTime = Time
    blTime = False
End Sub
```

The clock is turn off (blTime = False) when user click the button. You can add analogous code for other buttons as well but only the first click matters.
What we need is a way to get time that lapsed from the form. Use property:

```
Property Get Timespan() As Double
    If Not blTime Then
        Timespan = endTime - startTime
    Else
        Timespan = 0
End Property
```

Then, in module you can use command UserForm1.Timespan. Or format it nicely:

```
Format(UserForm1.Timespan, "hh:mm:dd")
```

Important: UserForm cannot be .Unload before, just .Hide.

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt something like this:

```
Sub CalculateRunTime_Minutes()
'PURPOSE: Determine how many minutes it took for code to completely run
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

'*****************************
'Insert Your Code Here...
'*****************************

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

To suit your needs. Source is [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/1/28/vba-calculate-macro-run-time)

You can learn more about VBA's `Timer` function [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/timer-function)

A second option would be to use the `Now` [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/now-function) which will give you the current time. So for example:

```
t = Now
.... run your tasks....
tfinal = Now
time_elapsed = tfinal - t
```

Comment: @Barbaaz Please mark my response as an answer if it has helped you :) Thanks.

Comment: I'm having some issues understanding the `Timer` function.
This is what I have so far. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WMYLnZ7s)